# selenium webdriver can't click on button using driver.find_element_by_css_selector

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

can't click on button using driver.find_element_by_css_selector

i try use this Locating Elements **driver.find_element_by_css_selector**
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#minicart-content-wrapper > div.block-content > div.actions-wrapper > div:nth-child(1) > div > a')`

and have this code
`<a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: shoppingCartUrl}" href="https:..." data-uw-styling-context="true" data-uw-rm-brl="false">                     <span data-bind="i18n: 'View and Edit Cart'" data-uw-styling-context="true">View Cart</span>                 </a>`

i try use the x_path `//*[@id="minicart-content-wrapper"]/div[2]/div[5]/div[1]/div/a` but it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML-DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//a[contains(.,'View Cart')]
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If it's a unique match then click it like below:

**Code trial 1:**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'View Cart')]").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(.,'View Cart')]"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Code trial 2 is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the html code provided in the query, the below locator strategies should work:

By CLASS_NAME:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'action viewcart'])
```

By CSS_SELECTOR:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.action viewcart'])
OR
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='action viewcart']")
```

By XPATH (with text):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='View Cart']")
```

By LINK_TEXT:

```
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'View Cart'])
```

By XPATH (with contains):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'View and Edit Cart')"])
```

Advise you to use `explict wait` such as `WebdriverWait` in order to wait until the element is visible/clickable, etc.